# qt5 yocto support for i.mx7 with pxp support

Tags: yocto, buildroot, build-system, imx6, nxp-microcontroller

I'am working on `i.mx7d` yocto. Now I want to compile Qt5 image for i.mx7 with `pxp support`, Because the i.mx7d does not have `gpu`. so I want to enable pxp support.
Can anyone guide me how to enable pxp in yocto and test in board.
Thanks in advance.

I have seen some vedios which shows the qt support in i.mx7 in youtube.

Note: Please tell me if buildroot have any support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at this patch that append qtbase for enables the use of GLES2 backend for Software Rendering allowing
SoCs without GPU support to use it. Up to now, this includes i.MX6UL
and i.MX7D.

Technically, when you have meta-fsl-arm and compile qtbase, the support is already there.

https://github.com/Freescale/meta-fsl-arm/commit/9356268bfb444b74a88491fca7a9d268ed72b561